# asp.net membership provider: Create user with different application name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I'm starting to use the membership provider. 
My first idea is to create 2 different mvc3 applications: one for the Web Site and the other to administer the first one. Each application has a different applicationName (WebSite and AdminWebSite).

I want to create Users of WebSite using the application AdminWebSite. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, can specify multiple providers and [reference them by provider name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.providers.aspx). Just make sure that the provider settings for WebSite in AdminWebSite are defined exactly the same way.